# Install requirements from Django project with VS Code

Tags: django, visual-studio-code, path, requirements

I try to run and open the development server of a Django project in VS Code, that I created with GidPod IDE.

When I open the project in GidPod (where I created it), install the requirements, create an env.py, set the 'SECRET_KEY' variable and I can start the server with `python3 manage.py runserver`. Then I open the exact same project in VS code, I create a virtual environment and install the requirements from requirements.txt as I did in GidPod with `pip3 install -r requirements.txt`. If I now try to start the development server, I get the following error:

```
(gh-env) PS C:\Users\SkywalkingTiger\Desktop\git-repos\gfeller-herbs-wf> python3 manage.py runserver
Performing system checks...

Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\threading.py", line 1038, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\threading.py", line 975, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\SkywalkingTiger\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\SkywalkingTiger\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 133, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "C:\Users\SkywalkingTiger\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 485, in check
    all_issues = checks.run_checks(
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\SkywalkingTiger\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 88, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\SkywalkingTiger\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 14, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\SkywalkingTiger\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 24, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\SkywalkingTiger\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 494, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\SkywalkingTiger\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 57, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\SkywalkingTiger\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 715, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\SkywalkingTiger\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 57, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\SkywalkingTiger\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 708, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1204, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1176, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1147, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 940, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\SkywalkingTiger\Desktop\git-repos\gfeller-herbs-wf\gfeller_herbs\urls.py", line 27, in <module>
    path("checkout/", include("checkout.urls")),
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\SkywalkingTiger\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\django\urls\conf.py", line 38, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1204, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1176, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1147, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 940, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\SkywalkingTiger\Desktop\git-repos\gfeller-herbs-wf\checkout\urls.py", line 2, in <module>
    from . import views
  File "C:\Users\SkywalkingTiger\Desktop\git-repos\gfeller-herbs-wf\checkout\views.py", line 13, in <module>
    import stripe
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'stripe'
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\threading.py", line 1038, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\threading.py", line 975, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\SkywalkingTiger\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\SkywalkingTiger\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 125, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "C:\Users\SkywalkingTiger\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 87, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[1]
  File "C:\Users\SkywalkingTiger\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 394, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "C:\Users\SkywalkingTiger\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\SkywalkingTiger\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\SkywalkingTiger\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 91, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\SkywalkingTiger\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 193, in create
    import_module(entry)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1204, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1140, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'storages'
```

Which indicates that 'django-storages' is not installed, although it is listed in requirements.txt and also in setting.py in installed apps.

When I run `pip3 show storages` or `pip3 show django-storgages` in the terminal it says: `WARNING: Package(s) not found: storages` or `WARNING: Package(s) not found: django-storages`.
When I run `pip3 freeze` this is the output:

```
asgiref==3.6.0
black==23.1.0
boto3==1.26.83
botocore==1.29.83        
certifi==2023.5.7        
charset-normalizer==3.1.0
click==8.1.3
colorama==0.4.6
defusedxml==0.7.1
dj-database-url==0.5.0
Django==3.2
django-allauth==0.41.0
django-countries==7.2.1
django-crispy-forms==1.14.0
django-storages==1.13.2
gunicorn==20.1.0
idna==3.4
jmespath==1.0.1
mypy-extensions==1.0.0
oauthlib==3.2.2
packaging==23.1
pathspec==0.11.0
Pillow==9.4.0
platformdirs==3.8.0
psycopg2==2.9.5
python-dateutil==2.8.2
python3-openid==3.2.0
pytz==2022.7
requests==2.31.0
requests-oauthlib==1.3.1
s3transfer==0.6.0
six==1.16.0
sqlparse==0.4.3
stripe==5.2.0
urllib3==1.26.16
```

So I suspect that the requirements are not installed correctly, maybe not in the right path?

This has been holding me up for several days now, which is why I'm turning to you. I am grateful for any help :-)

If you want to donwload the repo and try yourself, feel free..

https://github.com/LucaNoah/gfeller-herbs-wf/

If I run `pip3 -r requirements.txt` again this is the output:

```
(myenv) PS C:\Users\SkywalkingTiger\Desktop\git-repos\gfeller-herbs-wf> pip3 install -r requirements.txt
Collecting asgiref==3.6.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
  Using cached asgiref-3.6.0-py3-none-any.whl (23 kB)
Collecting black==23.1.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 2))
  Using cached black-23.1.0-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl (1.2 MB)
Collecting boto3==1.26.83 (from -r requirements.txt (line 3))
  Using cached boto3-1.26.83-py3-none-any.whl (134 kB)
Collecting botocore==1.29.83 (from -r requirements.txt (line 4))
  Using cached botocore-1.29.83-py3-none-any.whl (10.5 MB)
Collecting click==8.1.3 (from -r requirements.txt (line 5))
  Using cached click-8.1.3-py3-none-any.whl (96 kB)
Collecting dj-database-url==0.5.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 6))
  Using cached dj_database_url-0.5.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (5.5 kB)
Collecting Django==3.2 (from -r requirements.txt (line 7))
  Using cached Django-3.2-py3-none-any.whl (7.9 MB)
Collecting django-allauth==0.41.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 8))
  Using cached django_allauth-0.41.0-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting django-countries==7.2.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 9))
  Using cached django_countries-7.2.1-py3-none-any.whl (825 kB)
Collecting django-crispy-forms==1.14.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 10))
  Using cached django_crispy_forms-1.14.0-py3-none-any.whl (133 kB)
Collecting django-storages==1.13.2 (from -r requirements.txt (line 11))
  Using cached django_storages-1.13.2-py3-none-any.whl (46 kB)
Collecting gunicorn==20.1.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 12))
  Using cached gunicorn-20.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (79 kB)
Collecting jmespath==1.0.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 13))
  Using cached jmespath-1.0.1-py3-none-any.whl (20 kB)
Collecting oauthlib==3.2.2 (from -r requirements.txt (line 14))
  Using cached oauthlib-3.2.2-py3-none-any.whl (151 kB)
Collecting pathspec==0.11.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 15))
  Using cached pathspec-0.11.0-py3-none-any.whl (29 kB)
Collecting Pillow==9.4.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 16))
  Using cached Pillow-9.4.0-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl (2.5 MB)
Collecting psycopg2==2.9.5 (from -r requirements.txt (line 17))
  Using cached psycopg2-2.9.5-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl (1.2 MB)
Collecting python3-openid==3.2.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 18))
  Using cached python3_openid-3.2.0-py3-none-any.whl (133 kB)
Collecting pytz==2022.7 (from -r requirements.txt (line 19))
  Using cached pytz-2022.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl (499 kB)
Collecting requests-oauthlib==1.3.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 20))
  Using cached requests_oauthlib-1.3.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (23 kB)
Collecting s3transfer==0.6.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 21))
  Using cached s3transfer-0.6.0-py3-none-any.whl (79 kB)
Collecting sqlparse==0.4.3 (from -r requirements.txt (line 22))
  Using cached sqlparse-0.4.3-py3-none-any.whl (42 kB)
Collecting stripe==5.2.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 23))
  Using cached stripe-5.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (253 kB)
Collecting mypy-extensions>=0.4.3 (from black==23.1.0->-r requirements.txt (line 2))
  Using cached mypy_extensions-1.0.0-py3-none-any.whl (4.7 kB)
Collecting packaging>=22.0 (from black==23.1.0->-r requirements.txt (line 2))
  Using cached packaging-23.1-py3-none-any.whl (48 kB)
Collecting platformdirs>=2 (from black==23.1.0->-r requirements.txt (line 2))
  Using cached platformdirs-3.8.0-py3-none-any.whl (16 kB)
Collecting python-dateutil<3.0.0,>=2.1 (from botocore==1.29.83->-r requirements.txt (line 4))
  Using cached python_dateutil-2.8.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (247 kB)
Collecting urllib3<1.27,>=1.25.4 (from botocore==1.29.83->-r requirements.txt (line 4))
  Using cached urllib3-1.26.16-py2.py3-none-any.whl (143 kB)
Collecting colorama (from click==8.1.3->-r requirements.txt (line 5))
  Using cached colorama-0.4.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl (25 kB)
Collecting requests (from django-allauth==0.41.0->-r requirements.txt (line 8))
  Using cached requests-2.31.0-py3-none-any.whl (62 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools>=3.0 in c:\users\skywalkingtiger\desktop\git-repos\gfeller-herbs-wf\myenv\lib\site-packages (from gunicorn==20.1.0->-r reqCollecting defusedxml (from python3-openid==3.2.0->-r requirements.txt (line 18))
  Using cached defusedxml-0.7.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (25 kB)
Collecting six>=1.5 (from python-dateutil<3.0.0,>=2.1->botocore==1.29.83->-r requirements.txt (line 4))
  Using cached six-1.16.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (11 kB)
Collecting charset-normalizer<4,>=2 (from requests->django-allauth==0.41.0->-r requirements.txt (line 8))
  Using cached charset_normalizer-3.1.0-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl (96 kB)
Collecting idna<4,>=2.5 (from requests->django-allauth==0.41.0->-r requirements.txt (line 8))
  Using cached idna-3.4-py3-none-any.whl (61 kB)
Collecting certifi>=2017.4.17 (from requests->django-allauth==0.41.0->-r requirements.txt (line 8))
  Using cached certifi-2023.5.7-py3-none-any.whl (156 kB)
Installing collected packages: pytz, django-countries, dj-database-url, urllib3, sqlparse, six, psycopg2, platformdirs, Pillow, pathspec, packaging, oauthlib, mypy-extensions, jmespath, idna, gunicorn, django-crispy-forms, defusedxml, colorama, charset-normalizer, certifi, asgiref, requests, python3-openid, python-dateutil, Django, click, stripe, requests-oauthlib, django-storages, botocore, black, s3transfer, django-allauth, boto3
Successfully installed Django-3.2 Pillow-9.4.0 asgiref-3.6.0 black-23.1.0 boto3-1.26.83 botocore-1.29.83 certifi-2023.5.7 charset-normalizer-3.1.0 click-8.1.3 colorama-0.4.6 defusedxml-0.7.1 dj-database-url-0.5.0 django-allauth-0.41.0 django-countries-7.2.1 django-crispy-forms-1.14.0 django-storages-1.13.2 gunicorn-20.1.0 idna-3.4 jmespath-1.0.1 mypy-extensions-1.0.0 oauthlib-3.2.2 packaging-23.1 pathspec-0.11.0 platformdirs-3.8.0 psycopg2-2.9.5 python-dateutil-2.8.2 python3-openid-3.2.0 pytz-2022.7 requests-2.31.0 requests-oauthlib-1.3.1 s3transfer-0.6.0 six-1.16.0 sqlparse-0.4.3 stripe-5.2.0 urllib3-1.26.16
(myenv) PS C:\Users\SkywalkingTiger\Desktop\git-repos\gfeller-herbs-wf> pip3 install -r requirements.txt
Requirement already satisfied: asgiref==3.6.0 in c:\users\skywalkingtiger\desktop\git-repos\gfeller-herbs-wf\myenv\lib\site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 1)) (3.6.0)
Requirement already satisfied: black==23.1.0 in c:\users\skywalkingtiger\desktop\git-repos\gfeller-herbs-wf\myenv\lib\site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 
2)) (23.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: boto3==1.26.83 in c:\users\skywalkingtiger\desktop\git-repos\gfeller-herbs-wf\myenv\lib\site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 3)) (1.26.83)
Requirement already satisfied: botocore==1.29.83 in c:\users\skywalkingtiger\desktop\git-repos\gfeller-herbs-wf\myenv\lib\site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 4)) (1.29.83)
Requirement already satisfied: click==8.1.3 in c:\users\skywalkingtiger\desktop\git-repos\gfeller-herbs-wf\myenv\lib\site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 5)) (8.1.3)
Requirement already satisfied: dj-database-url==0.5.0 in c:\users\skywalkingtiger\desktop\git-repos\gfeller-herbs-wf\myenv\lib\site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 6)) (0.5.0)
Requirement already satisfied: Django==3.2 in c:\users\skywalkingtiger\desktop\git-repos\gfeller-herbs-wf\myenv\lib\site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 7)) (3.2)
Requirement already satisfied: django-allauth==0.41.0 in c:\users\skywalkingtiger\desktop\git-repos\gfeller-herbs-wf\myenv\lib\site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 8)) (0.41.0)
Requirement already satisfied: django-countries==7.2.1 in c:\users\skywalkingtiger\desktop\git-repos\gfeller-herbs-wf\myenv\lib\site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 9)) (7.2.1)
Requirement already satisfied: django-crispy-forms==1.14.0 in c:\users\skywalkingtiger\desktop\git-repos\gfeller-herbs-wf\myenv\lib\site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 10)) (1.14.0)
Requirement already satisfied: django-storages==1.13.2 in c:\users\skywalkingtiger\desktop\git-repos\gfeller-herbs-wf\myenv\lib\site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 11)) (1.13.2)
Requirement already satisfied: gunicorn==20.1.0 in c:\users\skywalkingtiger\desktop\git-repos\gfeller-herbs-wf\myenv\lib\site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 12)) (20.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: jmespath==1.0.1 in c:\users\skywalkingtiger\desktop\git-repos\gfeller-herbs-wf\myenv\lib\site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 13)) (1.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: oauthlib==3.2.2 in c:\users\skywalkingtiger\desktop\git-repos\gfeller-herbs-wf\myenv\lib\site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 14)) (3.2.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pathspec==0.11.0 in c:\users\skywalkingtiger\desktop\git-repos\gfeller-herbs-wf\myenv\lib\site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 15)) (0.11.0)
Requirement already satisfied: Pillow==9.4.0 in c:\users\skywalkingtiger\desktop\git-repos\gfeller-herbs-wf\myenv\lib\site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 
16)) (9.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: psycopg2==2.9.5 in c:\users\skywalkingtiger\desktop\git-repos\gfeller-herbs-wf\myenv\lib\site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 17)) (2.9.5)
Requirement already satisfied: python3-openid==3.2.0 in c:\users\skywalkingtiger\desktop\git-repos\gfeller-herbs-wf\myenv\lib\site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 18)) (3.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz==2022.7 in c:\users\skywalkingtiger\desktop\git-repos\gfeller-herbs-wf\myenv\lib\site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 19)) (2022.7)
Requirement already satisfied: requests-oauthlib==1.3.1 in c:\users\skywalkingtiger\desktop\git-repos\gfeller-herbs-wf\myenv\lib\site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 20)) (1.3.1)
Requirement already satisfied: s3transfer==0.6.0 in c:\users\skywalkingtiger\desktop\git-repos\gfeller-herbs-wf\myenv\lib\site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 21)) (0.6.0)
Requirement already satisfied: sqlparse==0.4.3 in c:\users\skywalkingtiger\desktop\git-repos\gfeller-herbs-wf\myenv\lib\site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 22)) (0.4.3)
Requirement already satisfied: stripe==5.2.0 in c:\users\skywalkingtiger\desktop\git-repos\gfeller-herbs-wf\myenv\lib\site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 
23)) (5.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: mypy-extensions>=0.4.3 in c:\users\skywalkingtiger\desktop\git-repos\gfeller-herbs-wf\myenv\lib\site-packages (from black==23.1.0->-r requirements.txt (line 2)) (1.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: packaging>=22.0 in c:\users\skywalkingtiger\desktop\git-repos\gfeller-herbs-wf\myenv\lib\site-packages (from black==23.1.0->-r requirements.txt (line 2)) (23.1)
Requirement already satisfied: platformdirs>=2 in c:\users\skywalkingtiger\desktop\git-repos\gfeller-herbs-wf\myenv\lib\site-packages (from black==23.1.0->-r requirements.txt (line 2)) (3.8.0)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil<3.0.0,>=2.1 in c:\users\skywalkingtiger\desktop\git-repos\gfeller-herbs-wf\myenv\lib\site-packages (from botocore==1.29.83->-r requirements.txt (line 4)) (2.8.2)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.27,>=1.25.4 in c:\users\skywalkingtiger\desktop\git-repos\gfeller-herbs-wf\myenv\lib\site-packages (from botocore==1.29.83->-r requirements.txt (line 4)) (1.26.16)
Requirement already satisfied: colorama in c:\users\skywalkingtiger\desktop\git-repos\gfeller-herbs-wf\myenv\lib\site-packages (from click==8.1.3->-r requirements.txt (line 5)) (0.4.6)
Requirement already satisfied: requests in c:\users\skywalkingtiger\desktop\git-repos\gfeller-herbs-wf\myenv\lib\site-packages (from django-allauth==0.41.0->-r requirements.txt (line 8)) (2.31.0)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools>=3.0 in c:\users\skywalkingtiger\desktop\git-repos\gfeller-herbs-wf\myenv\lib\site-packages (from gunicorn==20.1.0->-r requirements.txt (line 12)) (65.5.0)
Requirement already satisfied: defusedxml in c:\users\skywalkingtiger\desktop\git-repos\gfeller-herbs-wf\myenv\lib\site-packages (from python3-openid==3.2.0->-r requirements.txt (line 18)) (0.7.1)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in c:\users\skywalkingtiger\desktop\git-repos\gfeller-herbs-wf\myenv\lib\site-packages (from python-dateutil<3.0.0,>=2.1->botocore==1.29.83->-r requirements.txt (line 4)) (1.16.0)
Requirement already satisfied: charset-normalizer<4,>=2 in c:\users\skywalkingtiger\desktop\git-repos\gfeller-herbs-wf\myenv\lib\site-packages (from requests->django-allauth==0.41.0->-r requirements.txt (line 8)) (3.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<4,>=2.5 in c:\users\skywalkingtiger\desktop\git-repos\gfeller-herbs-wf\myenv\lib\site-packages (from requests->django-allauth==0.41.0->-r requirements.txt (line 8)) (3.4)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in c:\users\skywalkingtiger\desktop\git-repos\gfeller-herbs-wf\myenv\lib\site-packages (from requests->django-allauth==0.41.0->-r requirements.txt (line 8)) (2023.5.7)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the %PYTHONPATH% environment variable using `setx PYTHONPATH "pathToMyProject"` was the solution for me :-)

Answer (score 0):

Clean pip cache from folder `%LocalAppData%\pip\Cache`

Or upgrade pip and than purge your pip cache.

After cleaning cache. Try running `pip install` again

Comment: I did that and added the output to my question :-)

Comment: Remove pip cache from following folder. %LocalAppData%\pip\Cache